# Generate custom class at design time

Tags: c#, codedom

I have a component which has a collection of objects (DataProviders).
Each DataProvider has a unique name set by the user at design time.
How can I make the designer generate a class into an additional file which contains the names of the DataProviders?

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
public class DpContainer : Component
{
public DataProviderCollection collection = new DataProviderCollection();

  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
      DataProvider dataprovider1 = new DataProvider();
      dataprovider1.Name = "Provider 1";

      DataProvider dataprovider2 = new DataProvider();
      dataprovider2.Name = "Provider 2";

      collection.add(dataProvider1);
      collection.add(dataProvider2);
    }
  }
}
```

The generated class should look like this:

```
namespace DataProviderNamespace
{
  public class DataProviderNames
  {
    public const string Provider1 = "Provider 1";
    public const string Provider2 = "Provider 2";
  }
}
```

I would like to add this class as a designer.cs file.
Using CodeDom I am able to create this class, but unfortunetly i have to specify full path of file. Additionally I would like to make the class partial. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it does what you need, but have you looked at Text Template Transformation Toolkit([T4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx))?  We used it to generate code for data access components.  Comes with VS so it's not something additional you'd have to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found a solution (using DTE):
in Serialize method of custom CodeDomSetializer:

```
IDesignerSerializationManager manager;
EnvDTE._DTE dte = (DTE) manager.GetService(typeof(DTE));
```

from dte I get file name of actual document:

```
dte.ActiveDocument.FullName
```

Now I get current project:

```
ProjectItem proj = (ProjectItem)manager.GetService(typeof(ProjectItem));
```

and add new file to project:

```
proj.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(NewFile);
```